# 403 invalid csrf token, Express, csurf, React and Axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, csrf

I am trying to implement CSRF protection to my API endpoints,
I am using express and csurf, when making a post request using Axios from my react app I am receiving 403 invalid csrf token.
I have been searching all over for a solution but could not find one that fits.

For example, I am trying to send an Axios request to log out from the app (delete the session cookie) and receive the error.
A code that shows the error looks like that:

server.ts:

```
const router = express();

dotenv.config();
router.use(helmet...)
router.use(cookies());



router.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/build')));


var production = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? true : false;
 var csrfProtection = csurf({ cookie:{
     httpOnly:production,
     secure:production
 } });
 router.use(csrfProtection);



router.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: true
    ,exposedHeaders:['itemsCount','notificationCount','courseCount'] }));

router.use((req, res, next) => {

     res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', req.csrfToken(),{httpOnly:production,secure:production});
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, itemsCount');

    if (req.method == 'OPTIONS') {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, GET');
        return res.status(200).json({});
    }

    next();
});


router.use('/api', userRoute);



const httpServer = http.createServer(router);

httpServer.listen(config.server.port, () =>
    logging.info(NAMESPACE, `Server is running ${config.server.hostname}:${config.server.port}`));
```

user.ts:

```
router.post(`/${NAMESPACE}/logout`,verifyToken, logout);
```

userController.ts:

```
const logout = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  res.clearCookie('session');
  return sendResponse(res, 200);
}
```

the axios request looks like that:

```
logout: () => axios.post(`/users/logout`, {},{withCredentials: true})
```

Both XSRF-TOKEN and _csrf cookies are secure and httpOnly.

I would much appreciate it if someone can point me to what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks.